# Increase precision in tcl

Tags: tcl

How to increase the precision in tcl.
I am getting b2 below as -0.000001 whereas the actual value is -7.95553e-007

```
set b2 [lindex $b1 0]
```

I tried "set tcl_precision 12" but it did not change anything

Comment: What is `b1`, and how are *those values* calculated?

Comment: b1 is an output from my Structural analysis program, called as: set b1 [eleResponse $eleNum   defoANDforce]

Comment: Do you have control over the way it is calculated?

Comment: `lindex` has nothing to do with the precision of a number. The process that stores values into the `b1` list is where you need to look.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tcl these days uses a floating point rendering system that means by default it never loses any precision at all when a double-precision floating point number is automatically converted to a string and back, while simultaneously using the minimum number of decimal digits in the string. It has had this code since Tcl 8.5 and uses it whenever the `tcl_precision` global variable is set to its default value (`0` these days). In the future, this may well become a hard-core default, but I don't think it has done so yet.

Older versions of Tcl (all currently unsupported) instead used that `tcl_precision` global to control the number of decimal digits used; setting it to non-zero values still has that effect for backward compatibility. The old default value was 15, which *usually* did the right thing, but 17 ensures that no information is ever lost, even in tricky edge cases, but at a cost of often producing effectively noise digits at the end. (That is a consequence of the differences between arithmetic in base-2 and base-10, and are properly common to all languages that use IEEE binary floating point math.)

If you want to use a definite number of decimal digits after the point because you are producing output for human consumption, you should use the `format` command.

```
format %.5f 1.23; # >>> 1.23000
```

Comment: Tcl can only work with the precision actually present in the underlying number, which depends on the algorithm used and whatever custom code is in play. If that precision is gone, there isn't anything that the language runtime can do about it!